# debugfs_create_file doesn't create file

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I am trying to create a debugfs file using the debugfs_create_file(...). I have written a sample code for this.

```
static int __init mmapexample_module_init(void)                                 
 {                                                                               
         file1 = debugfs_create_file("mmap_example", 0644, NULL, NULL, &my_fops)\
 ;                                                                               
         printk(KERN_ALERT "Hello, World\n");                                    
         if(file1==NULL)                                                         
           {                                                                     
             printk(KERN_ALERT "Error occured\n");                               
           }                                                                     
         if(file1==-ENODEV)                                                      
           {                                                                     
             printk(KERN_ALERT "ENODEV occured\n");                              
           }                                                                     
         return 0;                                                               
 }
```

When i ran insmod i could get the Hello, World message but no the error message. So i think the debugfs_create_file worked fine. However i couldn't find any file in /sys/kernel/debug. The folder is there but it is empty. Can anyone help me with this? Thank you...

Thanks,
Bala

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For debugfs to work, you actually have to have a debugfs mountpoint:

```
mount -t debugfs none /sys/kernel/debug
```

Not sure if that's what the problem is here, but may be you can check if you have a mounted debugfs 
on /sys/kernel/debug

Answer (score 0):

You might consider `printk(KERN_ALERT "Something else happened\n")` in the case that file1 is not equal to `NULL` or `-ENODEV`.  That may provide some interesting results.  Maybe:

```
if (file1 == NULL)
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Error occurred\n");
else if (file1 == -ENODEV)
    printk(KERN_ALERT "ENODEV occurred\n");
else
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Something else occurred\n");
```

I'm not familiar with kernel programming libraries as much, but if there is a similar va_args interface to printk(), you could probably print the value of file1.

Now looking at this though, is there some kind of kernel `errno`?  Or is that what debugfs_create_file() returns?

**UPDATE**:

The only help I can give now is to somehow discover what file1's value is and investigate what that means.  You may want to do some poking around for an `errno` equivalent and see if its set.  Equivalent to the `perror()` call in the kernel basically.